# Stable Baselines - PPO Iterate through the data frame for learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

PPO model doesn't iterate through the whole dataframe .. its basically repeating the first step many times (10,000 in this example) ?

In this case, DF's shape is (5476, 28) and each step's obs shape is: (60, 28).. I dont see that its iterating through the whole DF.

```
# df shape - (5476, 28)
env = MyRLEnv(df)
model = PPO("MlpPolicy", env, verbose=4)
model.learn(total_timesteps=10000)


MyRLEnv:
self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(4)
self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=-np.inf, high=np.inf, shape=(60, 28) , dtype=np.float64)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is your dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

I also got stuck few days ago on something similar to this , but after inspecting deeply I found that the `learn` method actually runs the environment for `n` times , now this `n` is equal to `total_timesteps/size_of_df` , this in your case would be nearly `10000/5476`times which is almost equal to `1.8` , so this `1.8` means , the algorithm would reset the environment at the beginning, then run the `step` method for the entire dataframe and reset the environment again and run the step method for only 80% of the data in dataframe. So, when the `PPO` Algorithm stops you see only 80% of the dataframe is being ran .

The Actor Critic Algorithms runs the environment numerous number of times to improve it's efficiency, so that is the reason it is usually suggested that in order to get better results we should keep the value of `total_timesteps` fairly high , so that it can run it on the same data for quite some times to learn better.

`Example`:
Say my `total_timesteps` = 10000 and `len(df)` = 5000,
then in that case it would run for, `n = total_timesteps/len(df)` = 2 Full scans of the entire dataframe .